# Cant get param from delete method in web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api server and want to implement a delete function:

this is the function:

```
    public void Delete([FromBody]string identifier)
    {
        ExpressLogger.LogDebug("Enter");
        try
        {


            if (Utils.IsRmhUsed())
            {

                CustomerRmhDbRepository repo = new CustomerRmhDbRepository();
                repo.DelCustomer(identifier);
            }
            else
            {
                //If implement function for RMS
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExpressLogger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            HttpResponseMessage message = new 
            HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) { Content = new S 
            tringContent(ex.Message) };
            throw new HttpResponseException(message);
        }
    }
```

I call the method from postman with the following string 
http://10.0.0.129:5005/api/customer?identifier=000007

The call gets to the delete method but the variable identifer is NULL
I have tried like this to: http://10.0.0.129:5005/api/customer?000007

I also tried to use attribute like this:

```
[Route("{identifier}")]
```

When i do that it wont even 'go in the the method" Delete.

What can be wrong? Why cant i get the value from the variable identifier ?

Comment: Remove the [FromBody] attribute

Comment: @Nkosi thats verry strange, i did that before and it did not work, but now when i removed the [FromBody] it worked like a charm, thanks. You must have magic hands or something :) But i had to missed something before !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `[FromBody]` attribute in order to match

```
 http://10.0.0.129:5005/api/customer?identifier=000007
```

HTTP DELETE requests do not have a BODY and the model binder will bind the parameter from the query string.

If using the route template

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("{identifier}")]
public void Delete(string identifier) {
    //...
}
```

The URL will need to look like

```
http://10.0.0.129:5005/api/customer/000007
```

in order to match the route template

Comment: Now i only use public void Delete(string identifier) - is it better to use route template?

Comment: @Niklas it is a matter of choice and how you want the URL to look. Both approaches work